# MYSQL error with specific timestap value

Tags: mysql

This not works:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` VALUES
    (28,4,4,'simple','BCBSO2R',0,0,'2012-03-25 02:52:08','2015-05-19 12:20:53')
```

> 1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '2012-03-25 02:52:08' for column
>   'created_at' at row 1

But this works:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` VALUES 
    (28,4,4,'simple','BCBSO2R',0,0,'2012-03-25 01:52:08','2015-05-19 12:20:53')
```

**I changed only time from '2012-03-25 02:52:08' to '2012-03-25 01:52:08'  !!**

How it is possible that concrete value in table column `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Creation Time';  is not allowed?

EDIT: (full creation syntax)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog_product_entity`;

CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type ID',
  `attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set ID',
  `type_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'simple' COMMENT 'Type ID',
  `sku` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'SKU',
  `has_options` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Has Options',
  `required_options` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Required Options',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Creation Time',
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Update Time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` (`entity_type_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID` (`attribute_set_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_SKU` (`sku`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1510 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Table';
```

Comment: The datetime value seems quite valid.

Comment: Add ddl command `create table catalog_product_entity ...` to question

Comment: Of course cannot create constraints but without constraints, I created your table and it worked without problem. However, there is an interesting similar issue here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70188 it is about timezone.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: In a basic test, I can't reproduce the problem, [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72633/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the date/time does not exist (given the configuration server) because of the change to daylight saving time.

Test:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog_product_entity`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity` (
    ->   `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Creation Time'
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone := 'UTC';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SET time_zone := 'UTC';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%time_zone%';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| system_time_zone | UTC   |
| time_zone        | UTC   |
+------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity`
    ->   (`created_at`)
    -> VALUES 
    ->   ('2012-03-25 02:52:08');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone := 'Europe/Berlin';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SET time_zone := 'Europe/Berlin';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%time_zone%';
+------------------+---------------+
| Variable_name    | Value         |
+------------------+---------------+
| system_time_zone | UTC           |
| time_zone        | Europe/Berlin |
+------------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity`
    ->   (`created_at`)
    -> VALUES 
    ->   ('2012-03-25 02:52:08');
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2012-03-25 02:52:08' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

The date/time '2012-03-25 02:52:08' to Berlin, for example, is invalid because of the change to daylight saving time. See [Clock Changes in Berlin, Berlin, Germany in 2012](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/germany/berlin?year=2012).

> [11.3.1 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)
>
> ...
>
> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>   (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)
>
> ...